# Accessing the members of a struct referenced by a void pointer

Tags: c++

I've got a function that takes a void pointer as a parameter. I want to pass this function a pointer to a struct, and then access the values of that struct within the function.

```
//the struct
struct s{
    int val;
};

//the function tries to access the object
int callback(void* p_obj)
{    
    //try creating a new struct based on p_obj 
    s2 = *(struct s*)p_obj;
    std::cout << "VALUE IN CALLBACK: ";
    std::cout << s2.val << std::endl; //prints a big-ass int
    return 0;
}

//main calls the function
int main()
{
    s s1;
    s1.val = 42;
    void* p1 = &s;

    //show some output
    std::cout << "s1.val: ";
    std:cout << s1.val << std::endl; //prints 42

    //std::cout << "p1->val: "; 
    //std:cout << *(struct s*)p1->val << std::endl; //does not compile

    s p2 = *(struct s*)p1;
    std::cout << "p2.val: ";
    std:cout << p2.val << std::endl; //prints 42

    //call the function
    callback(&p1);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the output in the callback function to be

```
VALUE IN CALLBACK: 42
VALUE IN CALLBACK: 42
```

but, instead, I think it's printing a memory address

```
VALUE IN CALLBACK:1989685088
VALUE IN CALLBACK:1989685088
```

Trying to access the members of a void pointer directly results in an error.

```
int callback(void* p_obj)
{
    std::cout << "VALUE IN CALLBACK: ";
    std::cout << (struct s*)p_obj->val << std::endl;
}
```

```
error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
```

Why is this? How can I access the members of a struct that a void* is pointing to?

EDIT: Fixed some typos in the writeup

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `s2 = *(struct s)p_obj;` needs to be `s2 = *(struct s*)p_obj;`

Comment: Why you write C like code? Apparently someone is [teaching you c++ in wrong way](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk) (link is for your teacher).

Comment: Marek, I follow a company style guide. *shrug*

Comment: Here you have official [cpp core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md).

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors:

1. `*(struct s)p_obj` needs to be `*(struct s*)p_obj`, as `p_obj` is not a structure object.
2. Because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the expression `(struct s*)p_obj->val` is actually equal to `(struct s*)(p_obj->val)`. Which means you try to dereference the `void*` pointer and cast the member `val` to `struct s*`.

   You should do `((struct s*)p_obj)->val` to cast the pointer `p_obj`.

And more typos: `*void p_obj` is very much wrong, it should be `void* p_obj`. Please take care to copy-paste your [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not retype is as that might add extra errors not in your real code, which distracts from the actual errors and problems.

Comment: 1. was a typo in my writeup , my bad. The code I ran did use \*(struct s\*)p_obj.